# Textfield for start animation

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

I would like to use a textfield for set the second for start an animation
I would like to start an animation of colors 
example : start with red color and after two seconds change to yellow colors 
I don't write in the code but i change the seconds with a text filed with seconds
I set a text filed for set the color but i don't know how i can set a textfield for the seconds
how i can set a textfield with seconds ?

This is my code

```
NSString * chosenColor = ColorField.text;
        NSString * chosenColor1 = ColorField1.text;
        NSString * chosenColor2 = ColorField2.text;


if(maxHZ > 18000.000f and maxHZ < 18099.999f) {Image.backgroundColor = [UIColor valueForKey:chosenColor];}
        if(maxHZ > 18099.999f and maxHZ < 18199.999) {Image1.backgroundColor = [UIColor valueForKey:chosenColor1];}
        if(maxHZ > 18199.999f and maxHZ < 18299.999) {Image2.backgroundColor = [UIColor valueForKey:chosenColor2];}
```

Thanks